# Mostrar imagem depois de carregar via ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, dom

Olá,

Estou montando um site sem refresh. Quando o usuário clica na aba clientes são carregadas lâminas do mesmo, porém como as imagens embutidas tem uns 2mb e acabam carregando por parte.

Gostaria de saber se existe um evento que verifica se uma imagem adicionada pelo ajax foi totalmente carregada. No carregamento do site eu faço com o evento onload no body, mas depois de carregada a página, este evento não funciona mais.

PS: Já usei o success/complete do ajax, mas não funciona porque o meu ajax retorna uma string em html, que depois eu adiciono em uma div.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Acredito que o melhor é diminuir o tamanho das imagens

Comment: Infelizmente não existe esta possibilidade, e mesmo que existisse se o usuário estiver com uma conexão lenta as imagens irão demorar pra carregar independente do tamanho...

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solução:**

Bom, na verdade desde o início eu estava fazendo certo, o problema é que a imagem era carregada em uma div oculta, logo, quando eu mostrava a div oculta com a imagem dentro, ai sim a imagem seria renderizada.

Com isso, carreguei a página com todas as div's visíveis e com a div de carregamento por cima de todas elas, quando a página termina de ser carregada eu escondo todas as divs (menos a que eu quero mostrar ao usuário) e a imagem aparece totalmente renderizada!

PS: Não é recomendado usar imagens tão grandes como 4mb. Pois mesmo após ela ser carregada, a renderização da mesma pelo navegador fica lenta e acaba sendo mostrada em partes.

Problema resolvido!

Obrigado à todos que acompanharam e de alguma forma tentaram ajudar!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um *event load* para cada imagem que retornar do Ajax e chamar uma função quando todas forem carregadas.

Uma sugestão seria criar uma `div` oculta para receber o retorno do Ajax com as imagens, contar quantas imagens retornaram e fazer um `.each()` criando um `on load` para cada uma. As imagens ficarão carregando em oculto na `div`, e quando todas forem carregadas, você manda o HTML dessa `div` para o a `div` final e faz o `fadeIn()`.

Crie uma `div` oculta em qualquer lugar:

```
<div id="oculta"></div>
```

E coloque o CSS dela:

```
#oculta{
   display: none;
}
```

Crie uma função que irá fazer a transição:

```
function mostraDiv(){
   // envia o HTML da div oculta e faz o fadeIn na div principal
   $("#div-da-aba").html( $("#oculta").html() ).hide().fadeIn();
   $("#oculta").empty(); // esvazia div oculta
}
```

No `success` do Ajax:

```
success: function(data){
   $("#oculta").html(data); // envia o retorno para a div oculta

   var imgs = $("img", "#oculta"); // busca imagens pela tag img
   var imgs_conta = imgs.length; // conta o número de imagens
   var conta = 0; // seta um contador

   // aqui eu crio um event load para cada imagem
   imgs.each(function(i,e){
      e.onload = function(){
         conta++; // quando a imagem é carregada, incremento o contador

         // se o contador alcançar o número de imagens, chamo a função
         if(conta == imgs_conta) mostraDiv();
      }
   });
}
```

**Por que eu sugeri usar uma div oculta?**

Para que na `div` principal você possa colocar uma mensagem de "Abrindo..." ou "Carregando..." ou algum loader animado enquanto as imagens estão sendo carregadas em oculto.

Comment: Fiz um teste com este código, porém acontece a mesma coisa que com os outros códigos, a imagem está carregando (no network que eu vejo essa informação) e ele dispara o evento antes de ela terminar de carregar, por via das duvidas eu dei um console.log nas informações e ele me retorna extamente as 4 imagens que tem na página. Ou seja, não tem erro de escrita e nem de lógica, apenas o evento on("load") está retornando true mesmo sem ter sido carregado!

Comment: Aqui vc pode testar: http://dvdteste.hospedagemdesites.ws/stack/t5.php  coloquei 2 imagens com 19mb cada.

Comment: Mas ok, vou verificar melhor para ver.

Comment: O load termina com 6s e o finish termina com 11s, pode ser por isso, não? http://prntscr.com/jddv8y

Comment: No caso a imagem termina de aparecer quando o FINISH para e não quando o LOAD para...

Comment: Aqui funcionou perfeito, inclusive coloquei um console.log para avisar quando cada imagem é carregada. Só adicionei um setTimeout de 1 segundo na função pq o navegador demora um pouco pra exibir a imagem mesmo ela tendo sido carregada.

Comment: Eu notei no teu server. Enfim, obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar solucionar qualquer coisa atualizo aqui!

Comment: Ok amigo. Realmente eu não sei outra forma de fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

De forma simples com JavaScript puro:

```js
document.getElementById('IDdaImagem').addEventListener('load',function(){ 
    this.style.display = 'block'
})
```

```html
<img width="100px" heigth="100px" id="IDdaImagem" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG" alt="" style="display: none;">
```

Dai é só fazer a implementação no JQuery e usar os efeitos que quiser

Obs.: Se tiver demorando muito espere mais um pouco, é que peguei uma imagem muito grande para o efeito ficar bem visível